# delete jsonObject replace by undefined

Tags: javascript

Why if I remove element 0 of my json, it is replaced by "undefined", and I haven't a jsonArray with 1 element.

```js
var json = [
            {"name": "test", "position":1},
            {"name": "test2", "position":2}]
            

delete json[0]

console.log(json)
```

I want something like that :

```
[
  {
    "name": "test2",
    "position": 2
  }
]
```

I haven't seen post that resolved this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice):

> The `splice()` method changes the contents of an array by removing or
>   replacing existing elements and/or adding new elements.

```
json.splice(0, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! delete is for JSON and Splice for array, in my case, it was an array and not a json, thanks you

Answer (score 3):

json is an array not an object. `delete` won't work on array. Use `shift()` to remove the first element of the array. [Refer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift)

```js
json.splice(0, 1)
var json = [{
    "name": "test",
    "position": 1
  },
  {
    "name": "test2",
    "position": 2
  }
]


json.shift()

console.log(json)
```

You can also use splice to remove the object from array

```js
var json = [{
    "name": "test",
    "position": 1
  },
  {
    "name": "test2",
    "position": 2
  }
]


json.splice(0, 1)

console.log(json)
```

[Refer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Answer (score 2):

Use `splice`:

```
json.splice(0, 1);  // 1 item at position 0
```

The main reason I'm writing this answer is to comment that this has nothing to do with JSON -- you have a Javascript Object, not a JSON string.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I see the difference now !

Answer (score 0):

after delete json[0], You just must filter the values  like this

```
json.filter(x=>x)
```

https://codepen.io/pen/?editors=1111